# Exibir eventos de determinado dia com jquery.datapicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Este calendário de eventos com `datepicker` exibe todos os eventos do mês corrente, então, como exibir os eventos para o dia quando clicar em um determinado dia? Por exemplo, clique em 25 de abril, você recebe todos os eventos para esse dia.

Segue parte do JS onde faz o *print*.

```
 function print() {
     loadEvents();

     var dWeekDayOfMonthStart = new Date(dYear, dMonth, 1).getDay() - settings.firstDayOfWeek;

     if (dWeekDayOfMonthStart < 0) {
         dWeekDayOfMonthStart = 6 - ((dWeekDayOfMonthStart + 1) * -1);
     }

     var dLastDayOfMonth = new Date(dYear, dMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
     var dLastDayOfPreviousMonth = new Date(dYear, dMonth + 1, 0).getDate() - dWeekDayOfMonthStart + 1;
```

Comment: O resto da função não é pertinente ao seu problema? E o código HTML?

Comment: Ola Anderson,  o html chama  somente os js

Comment: Verifique o exemplo, e os fontes   http://www.py3uf.qsl.br/test/

Answer (score 0):

Se você inspecionar o elemento do calendário, poderá acessar a estrutura HTML gerada pelo plugin. É fácil notar que as `divs` que possuem eventos relacionados possuem a classe `.c-event`, junto com um atributo `data-event-day` que possui o dia do evento. Portanto, para interagirmos com os dias que possuem eventos, basta fazermos:

```
$(".c-event").on("click", function (e) {
    var day = $(this).attr("data-event-day");

    alert(day);
});
```

Desta forma, se o dia 25 possuir evento e clicarmos sobre ele, um alerta com o conteúdo 25 é exibido. Também pelo inspetor do navegador, podemos ver que os eventos que aparecem na tela possuem a classe `.c-event-item` e também possuem o mesmo atributo `data-event-day`. Desta forma, podemos determinar, conforme o valor deste atributo, quais os elementos que devem ser exibidos ou ocultados na página ao clicarmos em um dia. Isso é feito da seguinte forma:

```
$(".c-event").on("click", function (e) {
    var day = $(this).attr("data-event-day");

    $(".c-event-item[data-event-day!=" + day + "]").hide();
    $(".c-event-item[data-event-day=" + day + "]").show();
});
```

Assim, ao clicarmos no dia 25, apenas os eventos deste dia serão exibidos. Se clicarmos em outro dia, apenas os eventos deste serão exibidos.

Um exemplo pode ser visto funcionando [aqui](http://woss.eng.br/sopt/200455-datepicker/).

> **Todo**: o código funciona perfeitamente para eventos que já são carregados na página, mas não em eventos que estão fora do range inicial. Isso acontece porque o evento `click` somente é atribuído quando a página é carregada, mas não quando é alterado o range de dias, gerando novos elementos.